# Selenium python on Instagram for comments

Tags: instagram

Could you please tell me how to check the "aria_label" attribute for the "svg" tag using selenium python? I wrote this code, but it doesn't work for some reason. This code should work like this " Find the like button for comments on the page, and find the svg tag of this button, then go through all the buttons, if the svg attribute aria_label == "Like" then put likes, otherwise if aria_label == "Dislike" we display " but for some reason it does not work

```
# *The method of rating likes for comments*
                button_comments = driver.find_elements(
                    By.XPATH, ".//li/div/span/div/div"
                )

                aria_label_elements = driver.find_elements(
                    By.XPATH, ".//li/div/span/div/div/span/svg"
                )

                for button_comment, aria_label_element in zip(
                    button_comments, aria_label_elements
                ):
                    aria_label = aria_label_element.get_attribute("aria-label")

                    if aria_label == "Like":
                        print("There are no likes here yet, so let's add them")
                        button_comment.click()
                        time.sleep(random.randrange(3, 6))

                    elif aria_label == "Dislikes.":
                        print("We have already liked here")

                print("Comments have been liked")
```

This is a bot for instagram, namely to automatically like comments

I tried to solve the problem via Chat-GPT, but it didn't help